# Variável com valores diferentes para cada retorno while

Tags: php, sql

Meu problema é que a variável $compra possui valores diferentes a cada retorno do while, e não sei como eu seleciono qual deles é o menor

```
  while($dados=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $idenc = $dados["id"];
        $produto = $dados["produto"];
        $qtd = $dados["qtd"];
        $fornecedor = $dados["fornecedor"];

        $compra = $dados["compra"];


         echo "<h3><tr>"
            . "<td><center>$qtd</center></h3></td>"
            . "<td><center>$produto</center></h3></td>"

            . "<td><center>$compra</center></h3></td>"

            . "<td><center>$fornecedor</center></h3></td>"
            . "<td><form method='post' action='operacoesenc.php'>"
            . "<input type='hidden' name='idenc' value='$idenc'>"
            . "<input type='text' name='compra' value='$compra'>"
            . "<input type='hidden' name='operacao' value='excluir'>"
            . "<input type='submit' value='Cancelar'></h3>"
            . "</form>";
    }
```

Comment: A variável $compra puxa os dados do sql e, como tem mais de um produto na tabela, ela é diferente a cada loop do While. Eu queria destacar a linha em que o valor da $compra é menor, porém n sei como usar o min() e nem sei se essa é a forma correta para fazer o q eu quero. Alguém me ajuda ?

Comment: Poste seu comando SQL para podermos orientá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que você deseja, mas se for apenas ordenar a sua lista do menor valor da variável $compra para o maior é só dar um ORDER BY nomeDoCampo ASC no fim da sua query SQL.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT produto_nome as produto, produto_preco as preco FROM produtos ORDER BY produto_preco ASC
```

Retorno:

```
 +---------+-------+
 | produto | preco | 
 +---------+-------+
 | mouse   | 15    | 
 | teclado | 20    | 
 | fone    | 70    | 
 | monitor | 200   | 
 +---------+-------+
```

O MIN() é utilizado caso você queira mostrar apenas o registro de menor valor, ou seja, ele não retorna uma lista de registros. Ai nesse caso não teria lógica você utilizar um laço de repetição.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT produto_nome as produto, MIN(produto_preco) as preco FROM produtos
```

Retorno:

```
 +---------+-------+
 | produto | preco | 
 +---------+-------+
 | mouse   | 15    | 
 +---------+-------+
```